# Top rated products magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to display top rated products in magento 2

My block Toprated.php

```
   public function getTesting()
{

    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

    foreach($collection as $eachColl)
    {
        $storeId = $eachColl->getStore()->getId();
        $reviewSum = $this->reviewSummaryFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($eachColl->getId());

        $rated[] = array(
            'rating' => $reviewSum['rating_summary'],
            'name' => $eachColl->getName(),
            'url' => $eachColl->getUrlPath(),
            'product_sku' => $eachColl->getSku()
        );
        $rateds[$eachColl->getSku()] = $reviewSum['rating_summary'];

    }
  arsort($rateds);
    $rateds = array_slice($rateds, 0, 3);
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', '1');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('rating', array('in' => implode(",", $rateds)));

    return $collection;

}
```

my template toprated.phtml file

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $this->getTesting();

$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

?>

but phtml file not calling any data.what i did mistake here

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to show the new block ?

It is possible by edit/add a layout file in view/frontend/layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">      
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block
        template="[your template]"
        class="[your class]"
        name="[your name]"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

create layout file in view -> frontend -> templates -> layout , 
file name should be your routname_controllernamespace_controllername (controller->Index->index.php)
ex. blog_index_index file should be look like this

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Demo\Blog\Block\PostList" name="demo.list" template="Demo_Blog::list.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>`